# Async Named Pipes Using Objects C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn to play with named pipes for communication. The following code project does a great job showing what an example with a raw string.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes

I am wrestling with changing the sending of a raw string to send an object instead.

Can someone demonstrate how to send an Order instead of a string?

I have some code to send an object but having issues combining the code project with this idea..

Here is my pipeClient

```
  public class Order
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }


    class PipeClient
    {
        public void Send(string SendStr, string PipeName, int TimeOut = 1000)
        {
            try
            {
                NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "orders", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                // The connect function will indefinitely wait for the pipe to become available
                // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
                Order order = new Order()
                {
                    Address = SendStr,
                    CustomerName = "John",
                    ProductName = "Visual Studio 2015",
                    Quantity = 1
                };
                string serialised = Json.Net.JsonNet.Serialize(order);

                pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);
                Debug.WriteLine("[Client] Pipe connection established");

                byte[] _buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialised);
                pipeStream.BeginWrite(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, AsyncSend, pipeStream);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException oEX)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message);
            }
        }

        private void AsyncSend(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the pipe
                NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = (NamedPipeClientStream)iar.AsyncState;

                // End the write
                pipeStream.EndWrite(iar);
                pipeStream.Flush();
                pipeStream.Close();
                pipeStream.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception oEX)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(oEX.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

My code breaks here --> pipeStream.Connect(TimeOut);

Here is my server edits

```
 private void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the pipe
                NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
                // End waiting for the connection
                pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);

               StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               string messageChunk = string.Empty;
               byte[] buffer = new byte[255];

                do
                {
                    pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    messageChunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                    messageBuilder.Append(messageChunk);
                    buffer = new byte[buffer.Length];
                }
                while (!pipeServer.IsMessageComplete);
                //Order order = Json.Net.JsonNet.Deserialize<Order>(messageBuilder.ToString());
                PipeMessage.Invoke(messageBuilder.ToString());

                // Read the incoming message
                //pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, 255);

                // Convert byte buffer to string
                //string stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                //Debug.WriteLine(stringData + Environment.NewLine);

                // Pass message back to calling form
                //PipeMessage.Invoke(stringData);

                // Kill original sever and create new wait server
                pipeServer.Close();
                pipeServer = null;
                pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

                // Recursively wait for the connection again and again....
                pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), pipeServer);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
.
.
. Server Form 


   private void PipesMessageHandler(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new NewMessageDelegate(PipesMessageHandler), message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Order order = Json.Net.JsonNet.Deserialize<Order>(message);
                    txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text +
                                     Environment.NewLine + 
                                     String.Format("Address: {0}" +
                                                   "Customer: {1}" +
                                                   "Product: {2}" +
                                                   "Quantity: {3}", order.Address, order.CustomerName, order.ProductName, order.Quantity.ToString());
                    //txtMessage.Text = message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sending an object over a stream involves serializing the object, transmitting, then deserializing the other end. If the issue is that you're getting an exception on `.Connect()` then please include the details. Otherwise I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: @ChrisPickford asking to edit the CodeProject to use an object instead of a string.

Comment: A pipe has two ends, we can only see one end of it.  Look at the other end.

Comment: @HansPassant I posted my broken changes.

Comment: The pipe can handle only one format: a stream of bytes. So you could either convert the object to bytes (e.g. binary serialization) or convert it to a common string format (e.g. JSON or XML) and then encode the string into bytes (e.g. with UTF or ASCII encoding). The latter is more portable. You have to decide what sort of scheme you're going to use; you can't send an object literally.

Comment: @JohnWu yes I choose serialization. But there is something I am missing More than this. The NamedPipe constructor maybe? I posted my changes above

Comment: The changes on the server end don't seem to be enough to create a server pipe named "orders".  You also really need to get this going without a timeout, it makes debugging too difficult.

Comment: @HansPassant Imagine if a guy downloaded the CodeProject above and added an object and some serialization to the client and some deserialization to the server. What else might a guy need to alter to get whats working for a string working for an object?

Comment: 'My code breaks here' - Why? How? What is the exception?